# How to use FunctionScoreQueryBuilder in ES 6 java api?

Tags: java, elasticsearch-6

I want to upgrade from ES 1.7 to 6.0. I made all necessary changes and now I have a problem with FunctionScoreQueryBuilder.

I create a BoolQueryBuilder filter and works fine. Now I want to add score to my results but results are same with those I have without add ScoreFunction

```
ScoreFunctionBuilder fb = ScoreFunctionBuilders.scriptFunction("_score * (doc['field'].value!=0? 50000:1) ")

FunctionScoreQueryBuilder fsb = new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder(filter,fb)

SearchRequestBuilder srbPaged = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
            .setFetchSource(includes, excludes)
            .setQuery(fsb)
```

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted just change the value of field[score],
 you should sort results by score.
Just like

`srbPaged.sort("_score", SortOrder.DESC)`

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)